# Outdated wordpress theme not sure which plugin cause error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Getting fatal error on very outdated site not sure which plugin cuase this any ideas where to start?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-content/themes/orgafit/functions.php:614 Stack trace: #0 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(294): Orgafit_Funcs->cws_check_for_update(Object(stdClass)) #1 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Object(stdClass), Array) #2 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/option.php(1931): apply_filters('pre_set_site_tr...', Object(stdClass), 'update_themes') #3 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/update.php(635): set_site_transient('update_themes', Object(stdClass)) #4 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/update.php(841): wp_update_themes() #5 /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-includes/class- in /data/1/2/12296225-4ed8-45bd-aa9c-0af189177859/web/wp-content/themes/orgafit/functions.php on line 614

Comment: Unless you are comfortable hacking the theme, plugins and/or core files by placing back-trace calls and inspecting hooks, it might be easier to just restore from backup, if possible, or contact a developer.

Comment: I am not original creator and project was left by original admins theres no backups It looks like some critical plugin is outdated and stopped working looking for workarounds.

Comment: start checking wp-content/themes/orgafit/functions.php on line 614